clang-format: make function name and first parameter atomic
Is there a way to make it so that the first parameter of a function will never be put on a new line? For example:
ret = function(
     param1, &(struct thing){
           .member1 = 12;
           });

Should be:
ret = function(param1, 
           &(struct thing){
            .member1 = 123;
       });

From what I can tell, this is only an issue when the first parameter is followed by a struct initialization, so it may have something to do with that. Is there an option/set of options that may be causing this?
Here's the .clang-format file:
# Style is similar to Linux Kernel
# https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 8
UseTab: Always
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
BreakBeforeBraces: Linux
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
ColumnLimit: 80 
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentGotoLabels: false
RemoveBracesLLVM: true
SortIncludes: false
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
TabWidth: 8

